# Error: connect EINVAL 0.0.xx.xx:80 - Local (0.0.0.0:0)

Tags: coffeescript, hubot

I'm trying to use hubot msg object to send http request, but finally get this error:
Error: connect EINVAL 0.0.xx.xx:80 - Local (0.0.0.0:0)

A similar question is saying this is caused by hosts file, but no detail.

Comment: Whatever api you are hitting, make sure it has protocol mentioned. For e.g. http://<your_api_host>:<port>

Comment: Double check your <HOST>:<PORT> syntaxes. If it is a proxy_http problem, then, I think you can check this issue: [https://github.com/request/tunnel-agent/issues/39](https://github.com/request/tunnel-agent/issues/39)

Answer (score 33):

I've been seeing this problem multiple times during the last two years. In all cases it was what @Shiva said: either the protocol or the port was missing.

Here is the most recent occurrence of this problem a co-worker had with the axios module in a Node.js application:

`axios({ method: "get", url: "hostname:8080/liveness" })`

After prepending `http` it worked:

`axios({ method: "get", url: "http://hostname:8080/liveness" })`